# Kubernetes 1.16 deprecation of daemonset, statefulset, deployments and replicasets

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

1.16 deprecation notice:

```
DaemonSet, Deployment, StatefulSet, and ReplicaSet resources will no longer
 be served from extensions/v1beta1, apps/v1beta1, or apps/v1beta2 in v1.16. Migrate to the apps/v1 API, available since v1.9. Existing persisted data 
can be retrieved through the apps/v1 API. For example, to convert a 
Deployment that currently uses apps/v1beta1, enter the following command.
```

I have about 10 helm charts that contain the old api versions - datadog, nginx-ingress and more. I don't want to upgrade these different services. are there any known work arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options you should consider:

- don't update anything and just stick to Kubernetes 1.15 (not recommended as it is 4 main versions behind the latest one)
- `git clone` your repo and change `apiVersion` to `apps/v1` in all your resources
- use [kubectl convert](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#convert) in order to change the `apiVersion`, for example: `kubectl convert -f deployment.yaml --output-version apps/v1`

It is worth to mention that stuff gets deprecated for a reason and it is strongly not recommended to stick to old ways if they are not supported anymore.